# Separate Editing from Publishing for pages

Tags: pages

My site is made of "pages". Those page are static, but my team is going to modificated those pages frequently. I would like to have several authors and one editor.

The authors edit content, but cannot publish it.
The edito can edit content, but mainly validate and publish changes.

I was not able to do that.

One more thing, it would be great to separate my pages in section, so that each author can edit pages in his assigned section.

I could not find a way to do it in WP. I use WP 3.9.2

Tx !!!

Answer (score 0):

For your authors you need to set accounts with a "contributor" role. A contributor can writ content but can't publish it. Then create a user for your editor and give him an "editor" role and he will be able to publish the content the authors had written.

The main problem you may run into is that contributors can not upload images. If you trust your authors to not use your site to upload some porn or other "evil" images then you can use one of the role editing plugins to give this permission either for all the contributors or specific users.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that resolved my problem : revisionary
https://wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/